# How to know specific type on react-table CellContext

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-table

```
type Person = {
  age: number
  lastName: string
}

const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<Person>()

const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor('age', {
    cell: (info: CellContext<Person, number>) => info.getValue()
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('lastName', {
    cell: (info: CellContext<Person, String>) => info.getValue()
  }),
]
```

By using my editor I discovered that the type specifiers of

```
CellContext<Person, number>
```

and

```
CellContext<Person, String>
```

are correct, but if I didn't have my code editor, how could I have known this? How could I have known that the function assigned to `cell` would need to accept a param of `CellContext`, how was I supposed to know the `TData` was `Person` and how would I know that `TValue` was `number` or `string`? Yes, the `number` refers to `age` and `String` refers to `lastName` and I can see that. But I only understand this after being told the answer from my editor.

What documentation could I have looked at to discover this without my editor's help?

I'm new to Typescript, what aspects of typescript could I have used to discover the types/signatures of the cell functions on my own?

Comment: Since you've added `react-table` to the tags it seems you know what library `createColumnHelper<>()` is coming from. google `react-table` and you should be able find the docs for the respective version (you can find in `package.json`) that your code is using.

Comment: It's worth noting react-table types are a little weird in general, with having to often manually specify them like in this example. How you know is indeed a combination of inspecting it in the editor and then googling that in the docs or examples. You were doing what most people do already. Some projects (sadly, not enough) will use TSDoc to add additional explainers that surface in the IDE also. But it depends on the project/author.

Comment: Also (and I wonder if this is where part of the confusion is coming from) remember that TS types don't exist in the runtime at all, which is unlike languages like Java etc. So not adding this specifier through not knowing would not necessarily be inherently harmful to your application. It's need would have naturally come about when you needed to consume something that that more specific (than the inferred one) specifier gives you. But its all compile time. So there isn't really any need to go wondering "what else have I missed".